# Modifying output of child process to add a timestamp

Tags: linux, perl, unix, fork, pipe

I have a perl script which forks child processes.

```
sub my_exec{
    my($args,$stdout, $stderr) = @_;
    my $processes = fork();
    die("Cant fork") unless defined($processes);
    if(processes == 0){
        if(defined $stdout){
            close(STDOUT);
            open STDOUT, $stdout;
        }
        if(defined $stderr){
            close(STDERR);
            open STDERR, $stderr;
        }
        exec @$args;
    }else{
                ...
    }
}
```

My main issue is that I want to add a timestamp to every line of output to stderr. I was wondering if it could be done here. as you can see, stderr isn't always changed. I am assuming I could do it via some sort of pipe? I would also like to redirect the parent script(Daemon with both stdout and stderr redirected to files) to use timestamps as well.

Thanks

Comment: `open STDOUT,$stdout` opens an input filehandle -- not what you want.

Comment: well, $stdout would have something like ">out.log" in it

Comment: IPC::Run is probably what you want

Comment: Thanks. I am definitely looking at IPC::Run. But can this be done with the way I currently run stuff (fork and exec).

Comment: @Smartelf Yes, you can do it the low–level way. See my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19801597/123109).

Answer (score 2):

Say you write `my_exec` as below.

```
sub my_exec {
  my($args,$stdout,$stderr) = @_;  # caller untaints

  open my $oldout, ">&STDOUT" or die "$0: save STDOUT: $!";

  my $pid = open my $pipe, "-|" // die "$0: fork: $!";
  if ($pid) {
    if (defined $stderr) {
      open STDERR, ">", $stderr or die "$0: open: $!";
    }
    while (<$pipe>) {
      print STDERR scalar(localtime), ": ", $_;
    }
    close $pipe or die $! ? "$0: error closing $args->[0] pipe: $!"
                          : "$0: exit status " . ($? >> 8) . " from $args->[0]";
  }
  else {
    open STDERR, ">&STDOUT"    or die "$0: pipe STDERR: $!";
    if (defined $stdout) {
      open STDOUT, ">", $stdout or die "$0: open: $!";
    }
    else {
      open STDOUT, ">&", $oldout or die "$0: restore STDOUT: $!";
    }
    exec @$args or die "$0: exec @$args: $!";
  }
}
```

The main point is described in the [documentation on `open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html):

> If you open a pipe on the command `-` (that is, specify either `|-` or `-|` with the one– or two–argument forms of open), an implicit `fork` is done, so open returns twice: in the parent process it returns the pid of the child process, and in the child process it returns (a defined) `0`. Use `defined($pid)` or `//` to determine whether the open was successful.

The point of the implicit `fork` is setting up a pipe between the parent and child processes.

> The filehandle behaves normally for the parent, but I/O to that filehandle is piped from the `STDOUT` of the child process. In the child process, the filehandle isn’t opened—I/O happens from the new `STDOUT`.

That is almost perfect, except you want to modify the standard *error*, not the standard output.

This means we need to save the parent’s `STDOUT` so the child can restore it. This is what is happening with `$oldout`.

Duping the child’s (redirected) `STDOUT` onto its `STDERR` arranges for the underlying daemon’s standard error to run through the pipe, which the parent reads, modifies, and outputs.

One slightly tricky point is where the redirections are processed. If the caller wants to redirect `STDOUT`, that needs to happen in the child. But to redirect `STDERR`, the parent needs to do so because this gives the parent the opportunity to modify the stream.

The code for a complete example is of the following form. You mentioned a daemon, so I enabled [Perl’s dataflow analysis known as taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode).

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;

use v5.10.0;  # for defined-or //

$ENV{PATH} = "/bin:/usr/bin";

sub my_exec {
  # paste code above
}

#my_exec ["./mydaemon"];
#my_exec ["./mydaemon"], "my-stdout";
my_exec ["./mydaemon"], "my-stdout", "my-stderr";
```

With a simple `mydaemon` of

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

print "Hello world!\n";
warn  "This is a warning.\n";
die   "All done.\n";
```

the output is goes to separate files.

**1. `my-stdout`:**

```
Hello world!
```

**2. `my-stderr`:**

```
Tue Nov  5 17:58:20 2013: This is a warning.
Tue Nov  5 17:58:20 2013: All done.
./wrapper: exit status 255 from ./mydaemon at ./wrapper line 23.
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats a very detailed answer. 2 Quick questions. 1) This function will wait for the child to finish, correct? (It looks like it, just making sure) 2) The waiting won't affect perls signal handling (also seems good). The main reason I dont just use the system command, is I need to be able to have a responsive signal handler while the child is running. I just want to make sure I am not missing anything. Thanks Again.

Comment: @Smartelf 1) The `while` loop reads all output on `$pipe` and assumes that the child has exited when the `readline` fails. If you are concerned that the child process will close its standard error before exiting, you could add an additional `waitpid` before the call to `close`. 2) Assuming you’re using perl v5.8.0 or later, you should be in good shape thanks to deferred signals. See [“Interrupting IO” in the perlipc documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Interrupting-IO).

Answer (score 1):

`fork` is so low level. IPC::Open3 is the minimum you should use.

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

open(local *CHILD_STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
open(local *CHILD_STDOUT, '>', $stdout) or die $!;

my $pid = open3(
   '<&CHILD_STDIN',
   '>&CHILD_STDOUT',
   \local *CHILD_STDERR,
   $prog, @$args
);

open(my $stderr_fh, '>', $stderr) or die $!;
while (<CHILD_STDERR>) {
   print $stderr_fh $ts . $_;
}

waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Comment: prob want ``use POSIX`` and then ``$ts = strftime("%F %T", localtime);`` or similar in the CHILD_STDERR loop

Comment: Or before the loop. One often wants the same time stamp for the entire process.